# PowerShell Script for Outlook Signatures not working for all testing users

Tags: windows, powershell

I run an automated windows task via a GPO which runs the following powershell-script. The script, in short, takes template files from our storage server, copies them to the local office-signature path for outlook, replaces all placeholders with user-data and copies those files back onto our storage-server on a different file-path for another powershell-script on our Exchange-Server to set the signatures as our OWA-Signatures.

Here is the Script:

```
#Read .ost file-name (Outlook-Offline-File) and assigning variables:
$UserName = $env:USERNAME
$OstName = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Outlook\*.ost").Basename
$FileName = "Signatur ($OstName)"
$TemplateFileName = "test-signatur-template"
$FileExtension = "htm", "txt", "rtf"
#Signatur-Path of Template-Files(.htm,.txt,.rtf):
$PathSignaturTemplates = "REMOVED-FOR-PRIVACY-REASONS\templates"
$PathSignaturUser = "$env:AppData\Microsoft\Signatures"

#Path to copy user signatures to
$PathSignaturAufSYSVOL = "REMOVED-FOR-PRIVACY-REASONS\user-signaturen"


#Install PowerShell-AD-Cmdlets, if not already installed:
Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "Rsat.ActiveDirectory" -and $_.State -eq "NotPresent" } | Add-WindowsCapability -Online

#Read out user-data -> Table

$Table = Get-ADUser $UserName -Properties City, Company, Mail, OfficePhone, PostalCode, StreetAddress, Title

#Default-phonenumber if nothing set
if ($Table.OfficePhone-eq "" -or $Table.OfficePhone -eq $null){
        $Table.OfficePhone="REMOVED-FOR-PRIVACY";
    }

#Copy Templates to User-File-Path:
foreach ($Ext in $FileExtension) {
    Copy-Item -Force "$PathSignaturTemplates\$TemplateFileName.$Ext" "$PathSignaturUser\$FileName.$Ext"
}

#Replace Place-Holder in Templates with user-data from $Table
foreach ($Ext in $FileExtension) {
    (Get-Content -Path "$PathSignaturUser\$FileName.$Ext") |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@VORNAME@", $Table.GivenName  } |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@NACHNAME@", $Table.Surname } |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@TITLE@", $Table.Title } |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@MAIL@", $Table.Mail } |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@NAME@", $Table.Name } |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@PHONE@", $Table.OfficePhone } |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@POSTCODE@", $Table.PostalCode } |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@STREET@", $Table.StreetAddress } |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@CITY@", $Table.City } |

    Set-Content -Force -Path "$PathSignaturUser\$FileName.$Ext"

    #Copy finished Signature-Files to designated file-path for OWA-SIgnatures on Exchange
    Copy-Item -Force -Path "$PathSignaturUser\$FileName.$Ext" "$PathSignaturAufSYSVOL\$FileName.$Ext"
}

#If user has title "Technik" or "IT" create another signature
if ($Table.title -eq "Technik" -or $Table.title -eq "IT") {
    $NewTitle = $Table.Title
    $FileNameNew = "$NewTitle Signatur ($OstName)"
    $Table.OfficePhone = "REMOVED-FOR-PRIVACY"
    $Table.Mail = "REMOVED-FOR-PRIVACY"

    foreach ($Ext in $FileExtension) {
        Copy-Item -Force "$PathSignaturTemplates\$TemplateFileName.$Ext" "$PathSignaturUser\$FileNameNew.$Ext"
    }
    foreach ($Ext in $FileExtension) {
        (Get-Content -Path "$PathSignaturUser\$FileNameNew.$Ext") |
        ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@VORNAME@", $Table.GivenName  } |
        ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@NACHNAME@", $Table.Surname } |
        ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@TITLE@", $Table.Title } |
        ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@MAIL@", $Table.Mail } |
        ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@NAME@", $Table.Name } |
        ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@PHONE@", $Table.OfficePhone } |
        ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@POSTCODE@", $Table.PostalCode } |
        ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@STREET@", $Table.StreetAddress } |
        ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "@CITY@", $Table.City } |
        Set-Content -Force -Path "$PathSignaturUser\$FileNameNew.$Ext"

        #These signatures are local only, no OWA
    }

}

#Assign sig-files as New & Reply Signatures:
$Path = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings"
Remove-Item -Path $Path -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
New-Item -Path $Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
New-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Force -Name "NewSignature" -PropertyType ExpandString -Value $FileName
New-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Force -Name "ReplySignature" -PropertyType ExpandString -Value $FileName
```

THE TEMPLATE FILES (example) look like this:

```
Mit freundlichen Grüßen
@VORNAME@ @NACHNAME@
@TITLE@
--
REMOVED-FOR-PRIVACY
@STREET@, @POSTCODE@ @CITY@
Email: @MAIL@
Tel.: @PHONE@
REMOVED-FOR-PRIVACY
REMOVED-FOR-PRIVACY
REMOVED-FOR-PRIVACY
REMOVED-FOR-PRIVACY
REMOVED-FOR-PRIVACY
REMOVED-FOR-PRIVACY
```

The script runs perfectly fine for myself (first test-user), but:

- for another user the file-name is fine, but all place-holders are replaced with nothing "" or "," , so the signature files have no user-data.
- for another user everything is fine, but vowel-mutations we have in german like "äüöÄÖÜ" are replaced with a question mark, so "München" becomes "M?nchen"

-> All things above do not happen for all users and as I said none of the above errors happen for my user.

That's why I'm kinda lost on where to start looking.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: How are your colleagues executing/launching the script? The likeliest explanation is that the call to `Get-ADUser` fails and `$Table.<propertyName>` therefore always results in `$null` - try adding an explicit `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` after module installation, but before running `Get-ADUser`

Comment: For the user(s) with umlaut character replacements, what is their locale? That is to say, if you were to run something like `Get-Culture` for those **without** umlaut replacement, and those *with* umlaut replacement, would the outcomes match?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you for the advice, i've done that and it resolved the issues, unfortunately, only sometimes, the bug in my code still persists and happens sporadically and I cant seem to figure out why

Comment: @FiddlingAway great idea, but I've resolved the issue by using ISO-8859-2 encoding in the templates, error seems fixed now